# Перегрузка оператор присвоения

Tags: c++

Изучаю язык. Написал простенький класс:

```cpp
class Point{
public:
  Point();
  Point(int x, int y);      
private:
  int _x;
  int _y;
}
```

Захотел преобразовать его в другой тип. По не знанию и паскалевской привычки
написал такой оператор:

```cpp
int operator=(const Point& src);
```

Скомпилировал класс вместе с оператором и все нормально скомпилировалось.
Решил проверить на коде:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Point pt(1, 2);    
  int i;
  i = pt;
}
```

Компиляция не удалась:

```cpp
main.cpp:14: ошибка: cannot convert 'Point' to 'int' in assignment
```

Потом я нашел как преобразовать тип через другой оператор. Но мне интересно, раз компилятор дал мне скомпилировать этот оператор, значит наверно его, как то можно применить.

Вопрос: Что это оператор делает и как его можно использовать?

Comment: лучше перегрузи в таком случае оператор приведения типа

Comment: ну я уже понял что "operator int()" будет лутше написать, интересует что конкретно делает тот который я написал

Comment: Здесь ничего) Вот если бы Вы в классе Int написали такую функцию, то все бы запустилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо различать оператор присвоения и функцию преобразования.

Оператор присвоения  не меняет тип объекта, которому присваивается выражение.

В вашем примере

```
class Point{
public:
    //...
    int operator=(const Point& src); 
    //...
};
```

оператор присваивания присваивает выражение объекту класса `Point`. Причем присваиваемое выражение имеет также ссылочный тип класса `Point`.

Вы можете использовать возвращаемое значение выражения с данным оператором присваивания, чтобы присвоить его переменной типа `int`.

Например,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Point pt(1, 2);    
  int i;
  i = pt = pt;
}
```

Так как операторы присваивания выполняются справа налево, то сначала бы выполнилось присваивание

```
pt = pt
```

результатом которого было бы значение типа `int`, и только во втором присваивании это значение было бы занесено в переменную `i`

Если же вы хотите написать оператор преобразования, то он может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
operator int() const;
```

И тогда вы можете записать

```
  i = pt;
```

Имейте в виду, что для не пользовательских типов вы не можете переопределить оператор присваивания. И в этом предложении

```
  i = pt;
```

используется стандартное присваивание для целых чисел. Но так как `pt` не имеет целочисленный тип, то компилятор пытается его преобразовать к объекту целочисленного типа и вызывает для `pt` оператор

```
operator int() const;
```

если вы его определили. Иначе компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: все ясно, благодарю

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы пишете `a = b`, это транслируется как `a.operator=(b)`.

То есть, для вашего случая (`i = pt`) вам нужно бы перегрузить оператор присваивания у `i`, в типе данных `int`. Это, очевидно, невозможно.

Правильный путь — [оператор преобразования типов](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) `operator int() const`.

---

Заметьте, что другие, сложные операторы присваивания вполне можно перегрузить и вне класса-получателя. Например, `operator +=` ([пример](http://ideone.com/pvj6Mk)):

```
class Point
{
public:
  Point() : _x(), _y() {}
  Point(int x, int y) : _x(x), _y(y) {}

  friend int& operator += (int& i, const Point& pt)
  {
    i += pt._x;
    i += pt._y;
    return i;
  }

private:
  int _x;
  int _y;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Интересно то, что никто так и не показал как реализовать оператор присваивания...

```
class Point {

public:
    Point();
    Point( int x, int y );

    Point & operator = ( const Point & rhs ) {
        if ( &rhs != this ) {
            _x = rhs._x;
            _y = rhs._y;
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Выше все ответили правильно.
Забавно, что если использовать Ваше описание класса Point, то можно написать следующее:

```
Point x(1, 2);
Point y(3, 4);
int i = y = x;
```

И в i останется то, что Вы хотели получить.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int v) {this->v = v;}
    A(const A &a) { v = a.v; }
    int operator= (const A &a) { this->v = a.v; return v; }
private:
    int v;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A x(1);
    A y(2);
    int i = y = x;
    cout << i;
}
```

выводит как раз 1

Comment: P.S. Антону Сазонову, мой пример показывает, что присваивание не обязано быть реализовано так, как у Вас. Хотя Ваш пример безусловно классически правильный.